# Passing multiple methods into Apex 'rendered' attribute

Tags: apex, rendered

Can I pass a second method into the rendered attribute of the following apex element?

```
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!(firstMethod == true)}">           
        <img class="refresh_btn" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Images, 'images/icon_refresh.png')}" alt=""/>
    </apex:outputText>
```

Would this work?

```
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!(firstMethod == true)} && {!(secondMethod == true)}">          
        <img class="refresh_btn" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Images, 'images/icon_refresh.png')}" alt=""/>
    </apex:outputText>
```

So both firstMethod and secondMethod must return true for the element to render.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, although your syntax is a little off. The following should work:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!(firstMethod == true) && (secondMethod == true)}">
```

Which you should be able to reduce to:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!firstMethod && secondMethod}">
```

Comment: Cheers Alex, appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that, but like this:

```
rendered="{!firstMethod == true && secondMethod == true}"
```

Alternative use `AND` function:

```
rendered="{!AND(firstMethod, secondMethod)}"
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer mast0r!